# Why some Map Implementations throw Exceptions on get and other do not

Tags: java, dictionary, generics, exception

The Java Api for Map says in the description of get:

```
Throws:
ClassCastException - if the key is of an inappropriate type for this map (optional)
NullPointerException - if the specified key is null and this map does not permit null keys (optional)
```

Why are this exceptions optional? Or, why some implementations (e.g. HashMap) do not throw them, but others (e.g. ConcurrentSkipList) do?

What is the advantage of that? 
And how to deal with that, if I dont know which Map Implementation i am working with?

Comment: We can't easily determine why certain decisions were made 20 years ago.

Comment: i thought maybe there is a good explanation for that, i didnt think about.

Comment: if you don't know the implementation, then you have to validate your parameter for the `get()` method. 1.) check if it's the correct type 2.) check if it is not null

Answer (score 0):

From [javadocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#optional-restrictions)

> Some collection implementations have restrictions on the elements that
>   they may contain. For example, some implementations prohibit null
>   elements, and some have restrictions on the types of their elements.
>   Attempting to add an ineligible element throws an unchecked exception,
>   typically NullPointerException or ClassCastException. Attempting to
>   query the presence of an ineligible element may throw an exception, or
>   it may simply return false; some implementations will exhibit the
>   former behavior and some will exhibit the latter. More generally,
>   attempting an operation on an ineligible element whose completion
>   would not result in the insertion of an ineligible element into the
>   collection may throw an exception or it may succeed, at the option of
>   the implementation. Such exceptions are marked as "optional" in the
>   specification for this interface.

Comment: i read this. still i dont understand what is the advantage of that, especially if dealing with instances of maps where i dont know the exact implementation.

Comment: @T_01 I don't think there is any advantage to this. It's probably just some baggage left from the old times that can't be changed since Java is all _backwards compatible_.

Comment: Under no circumstances should anyone catch NullPointerException.  That exception means you, the programmer, made a mistake—you should fix it, not catch it.  The same is usually true for ClassCastException.

Answer (score 0):

The technical answer is that some map implementations need the keys to be of a specific class and not null. The most basic example for this is the EnumMap which needs keys which are enum objects. This is because the ordinal number of the enum object is used to look up the value in a simple backing array. The HashMap does not need keys to be objects of a specific class to function. It uses the standard hashCode() method defined in the Object class which all other classes inherit from.

From a design perspective the answer is twofold:

1) It gives more freedom of choice and makes different implementations slightly easier.

2) It allows them to change their mind in the future and do versions which throw exceptions and others which don't. If the general programming style changes over the years they can offer an alternative solution to people with different tastes.